# IntelliJ IDEA crashes with FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have just downloaded intellij idea and run it with ./idea.sh
But after creating a maven project, it crashes and I get this error:

```
./idea.sh 
[JetBrains Runtime] Detected slow X11, switched off alpha compositing of images. Control with -Dremote.x11.workaround={true|false|auto}.
2021-07-27 17:53:36,560 [  69040]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - real size = 4096 
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /root/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.1/frameworks/detection/test1.16fb203f/files.len
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:371)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:422)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:156)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.readLength(ResizeableMappedFile.java:178)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.<init>(ResizeableMappedFile.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:73)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumerator.createDefaultEnumerator(PersistentEnumerator.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentMapImpl.<init>(PersistentMapImpl.java:131)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentMapBuilder.buildImplementation(PersistentMapBuilder.java:64)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentMapBuilder.build(PersistentMapBuilder.java:41)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:39)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:60)
    at com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.DetectedFrameworksData.<init>(DetectedFrameworksData.java:37)
    at com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FrameworkDetectionManager.doInitialize(FrameworkDetectionManager.java:128)
    at com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FrameworkDetectionManager.<init>(FrameworkDetectionManager.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:771)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:35)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:110)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:64)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:340)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectExImpl.init(ProjectExImpl.kt:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:175)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.newProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:203)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.createProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ProjectBuilder.createProject(ProjectBuilder.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.AbstractMavenModuleBuilder.createProject(AbstractMavenModuleBuilder.java:233)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.doCreate(NewProjectUtil.java:118)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.createFromWizard(NewProjectUtil.java:73)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.createFromWizard(NewProjectUtil.java:68)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.createNewProject(NewProjectUtil.java:63)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.NewProjectAction.actionPerformed(NewProjectAction.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAware$5(ActionUtil.java:273)
    at com.intellij.util.SlowOperations.lambda$allowSlowOperations$0(SlowOperations.java:77)
    at com.intellij.util.SlowOperations.allowSlowOperations(SlowOperations.java:64)
    at com.intellij.util.SlowOperations.allowSlowOperations(SlowOperations.java:76)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:273)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:267)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.performAnActionForComponent(WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreenActionsUtil$LargeIconWithTextWrapper.lambda$new$0(WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.java:125)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:270)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6652)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6417)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5027)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4859)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2784)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4859)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:969)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:906)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:836)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:808)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:781)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:502)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2021-07-27 17:53:36,597 [  69077]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3  Build #IC-211.7628.21 
2021-07-27 17:53:36,616 [  69096]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - JDK: 11.0.11; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2021-07-27 17:53:36,617 [  69097]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - OS: Linux 
2021-07-27 17:53:36,618 [  69098]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - Last Action: WelcomeScreen.CreateNewProject 
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
[0727/175341.267951:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
root@robin:/home/robin/ideaIC-2021.1.3/idea-IC-211.7628.21/bin#
```

Why?

Comment: It seems that the file `files.len` does not exist at the specified path.

Comment: @TheHeadRush What can I do? Thanks :)

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248140. You can try adding `-Dide.browser.jcef.enabled=false` in the [.vmoptions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) file. The exceptions in the first part of the log are not related to the crash.

Comment: Does IntelliJ have the rights to write on that folder? That's a technical cache file that it should have created right before opening...

Answer (score 3):

Please [see the corresponding YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248140) for more details.

You can try adding

`-Dide.browser.jcef.enabled=false`

in the [.vmoptions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) file as a workaround.

The exceptions in the first part of the log are not related to the crash. You need to check the crash log instead (`java_error_in_*.log` in the user's home directory).

Comment: Thanks. By adding that line in idea.vmoptions, then it works. But why do I have to do that?

Comment: It disables JCEF component (Chromium browser inside the JVM used to render HTML pages). It crashes on some Linux versions for various reasons, see also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016421559-JCEF-the-missing-libs-problem-on-Linux.

Answer (score 1):

This happened in my PC for every project, that has a `README.md` file (generally cloned from GitHub).

I opened some other project, that don't have the `README` file, and disabled the Markdown plugin from `settings > Plugins > installed list of  plugins`.

After that, if you restart, it won't render the README, but it'll atleast open the project.

Comment: Bingo. I disabled Markdown, restarted IDEA, opened the readme, enabled the plugin - and the error happened again right away. For me it's not a complete crash, just a message telling "gpu process restarts too many times", and very high cpu usage.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The comment [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-317401/Too-many-restarts-of-GPU-process-adding-a-development-build-of-jar#focus=Comments-27-8806472.0-0) fixed it for me.

It is disabling the sandbox of JCEF.
Just disable JCEF is not a solution, as that what make it impossible to see e.g. a preview of a `.md` file.

Steps to fix it are:

- Select Find Action from the Help menu (or press CTRL+SHIFT+a)
- Enter Registry and select `Registry...`
- Find the `ide.browser.jcef.sandbox.enable` option in the list that appears and disable it
- Restart the IDE

This fix should work for all Jetbrains products.